# Incorporate Regex into delimiter for TIDYR

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to restructure my data and it gets hung up on certain cell strings, so I’d like to adjust it so the delimiter is only the following situation:

```
-End of word
-“;”
-1 space
-Capitol Letter
```

I'm new to REGEX, but this appears to capture what I’m looking for:

```
";\s[A-Z]"
```

BUT, it also includes the first letter of the second word, which I don’t want to be part of the delimiter. And I'm not exactly sure how to incorporate it into my "separate_rows" statement.

```
     # Create test data
               mydata <- as.data.frame(c("Column1 = answer1; Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2","Column1 = answer1; Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2","Column1 = answer1; Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2")) 
names(mydata) <- "TEST"
mydata$TEST <- as.character(mydata$TEST)

        # convert to 2 columns with a row counter
        mydata %>% 
        mutate(row=row.names(mydata)) %>%
        separate_rows(TEST, sep = '; ')
```

Current output:

```
row|TEST
1|Column1 = answer1
1|Column2 = answer2
1|incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
2|Column1 = answer1
2|Column2 = answer2
2|incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
3|Column1 = answer1
3|Column2 = answer2
3|incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
```

Output I'm looking for:

```
row|TEST
1|Column1 = answer1
1|Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
2|Column1 = answer1
2|Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
3|Column1 = answer1
3|Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `positive lookaround` (lookahead in your case) to solve your problem:

Read: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

```
library(tidyverse)
    mydata <- as.data.frame(c("Column1 = answer1; Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2","Column1 = answer1; Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2","Column1 = answer1; Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2")) 
    names(mydata) <- "TEST"
    mydata$TEST <- as.character(mydata$TEST)
    View(mydata)
    library(tidyverse)
    mydata %>% 
      mutate(row=row.names(mydata)) %>%
      separate_rows(TEST, sep = ';(?=\\s[A-Z])')
```

**OUtput**:

```
    row
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   3
                                                                           TEST
1                                                             Column1 = answer1
2  Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
3                                                             Column1 = answer1
4  Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
5                                                             Column1 = answer1
6  Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
```

The regex inside parenthesis would check the pattern but would not capture it.Hence elements during the match will never get eaten in a match.

Answer (score 1):

We can `mutate` to different delimiter and then do the `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(mydata, 'rn') %>%  
       mutate(TEST = sub(";\\s+(?=Column)", ",", TEST, perl = TRUE)) %>%
       separate_rows(TEST, sep=",")
#  rn                                                                         TEST
#1  1                                                            Column1 = answer1
#2  1 Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
#3  2                                                            Column1 = answer1
#4  2 Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
#5  3                                                            Column1 = answer1
#6  3 Column2 = answer2;  incorrectly formatted - should be connected with answer2
```